# Are there any passenger trains from Sweden to Finland?

Tags: trains, sweden, finland

I know about buses and ferries, [Rail transport in Finland page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rail_transport_in_Finland) does not say if they are passenger trains

[image]

[VR page](https://www.vr.fi/cs/vr/en/frontpage) shows only trains to Russia.

[image]

Comment: The [Seat 61 page on Finland](http://seat61.com/Finland.htm) suggests ferries rather than trains to get between Sweden and Finland. Given just how far north it is that the two countries join, and the lack of information on [seat 61 about trains between the two](http://seat61.com/Finland.htm), I'm assuming it's a "no"

Comment: Finland and Sweden use a different rail gauge, making rail travel more costly.

Comment: If this is a real question, and not just curiosity, I have taken one of those ferries, and I recommend it.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus So am I, but they had no wifi on 2011, I am thinking of trying it again, with the family this time

Comment: @User According to the Viking Line website, *some* cabins and many public areas have WiFi. We took the overnight ferry, and, frankly, after dinner and with early morning arrival, no computer play time.

Comment: If you had an unlimited budget, you could presumably charter a train, but there are no scheduled passenger services.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, there are no passenger trains between Finland and Sweden. There is actually a train line crossing the border between Haparanda and Tornio, but it is currently (since 1988) only used by freight trains.

Coming from Sweden, you could take a train to Luleå, from which you have to bridge about 160km on the bus to Kemi, where you will have access to the Finnish passenger train network again.

Comment: Update: there are now trains to Haparanda (Sweden).  There are also trains to Tornio (Finland), bringing the two train stations within walking distance from each other.

Comment: @gerrit To Haparanda, yes, but is there really passenger traffic at the 'regular' train station in Tornio? YR does not even list the station in their route planner. It seems to me as if the single daily train (the night trains to and from Helsinki) only stops at Tornio Itäinen, which is in the outskirts of Tornio and about a one hour walk from the train station in Haparanada. With much more frequent departures in Kemi, it is for most practical purposes probably still better to go there by bus.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right; I didn't realise Tornio-Itäinen was far out.  The one-hour walk might work for some travellers, or it could be done by local public transportation, but indeed there are more alternatives if taking a bus to Kemi.  Still, 4,5 km is much shorter than 160 km :)

Comment: @gerrit I had recently read about it, but couldn't the information right away, though now I did. It is at least announced that passenger traffic from Haparanda C towards Finland will commence in Ocotober 2024. The line will be electrified and there will be built a new passenger platform at the already present broad gauge tracks at Haparanda C station, so that Finnish passenger trains can continue across the border to Haparanda.

Answer (score 12):

According to [EGTRE](http://egtre.info/wiki/Border_Crossings:_Finland_-_Sweden), the single rail border crossing between Sweden and Finland carries freight only.

Sweden and Finland use different track gauges, and freight is transshipped between Swedish and Finnish cars in Haparanda. The line across the border is dual-gauge, but according to EGTRE the standard-gauge track does not see regular use.

Answer (score 8):

There is ongoing work to allow new passenger train services between Finland and Sweden in the future.  A resumption of such services is planned and might start in 2025 or later.

The railway between Haparanda (Sweden) and Laurila (Finland) [is being electrified](https://vayla.fi/en/laurila-tornio-haparanda) (22 km in Finland and 1 km in Sweden).   Additionally, on the Swedish side, [a new platform is planned to be built at Haparanda station in 2024](https://www.trafikverket.se/vara-projekt/projekt-i-norrbottens-lan/haparandabanan-haparanda-elektrifiering-och-plattform-for-finsk-trafik/) for passenger trains to Finland.  A [possibly dated article](https://traveltomorrow.com/passenger-train-service-between-finland-and-sweden-to-be-available-as-early-as-2025/) indicates a starting year of 2025.  See also [this article in the Barents Observer from 2021](https://thebarentsobserver.com/en/travel/2021/11/work-set-begin-cross-border-finland-sweden-rail-line).